# Problem with vector calculation.

Tags: analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

> **Problem**
>
> Let $\text{ABC}$ be a triangle and let $\text{A'}$ , $\text{B'}$ and $\text{C'}$ be respectively the center of $\text{[BC]}$ , $\text{[AC]}$ and $\text{[AB]}$.
>
> 1. Prove that: $\vec{\text{AA'}}+\vec{\text{BB'}}+\vec{\text{CC'}}=\vec{\text{0}}$
> 2. Let $\text{E}$ be a point in the vector plane, and $\text{G}$, $\text{F}$ are points where $\vec{\text{EF}}=\vec{\text{CC'}}$ and $\vec{\text{EG}}=\vec{\text{BB'}}$, and $\text{I}$ is the center of $\text{[FG]}$.
>
>    Prove that: $\vec{\text{EI}}=x \cdot \vec{\text{CB}}$ or $\vec{\text{CB}}=x \cdot \vec{\text{EI}}$

For the first one, it is easy:

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{\text{CA}}+\vec{\text{AB}}&=\vec{\text{CB}}\\
\vec{\text{CA}}+\vec{\text{AB}}+\vec{\text{BC}}&=\vec{\text{0}}\\
\vec{\text{CA}}+\vec{\text{AC'}}+\vec{\text{AB}}+\vec{\text{BA'}}+\vec{\text{CB}}+\vec{\text{BC'}}&=\vec{\text{AC'}}+\vec{\text{BA'}}+\vec{\text{CB'}}\\
\vec{\text{CC'}}+\vec{\text{BB'}}+\vec{\text{AA'}}&=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{\text{AB}}+\vec{\text{BC}}+\vec{\text{CA}})\\
&=\vec{\text{0}}
\end{align}$$

For the second one, I failed at all the attempts, and started wondering if the problem was at those equations: $\vec{\text{EF}}=\vec{\text{CC'}}$ and $\vec{\text{EG}}=\vec{\text{BB'}}$. So, are they correct, that is, can we  prove that: $\vec{\text{EI}}=x \cdot \vec{\text{CB}}$ or $\vec{\text{CB}}=x \cdot \vec{\text{EI}}$ using them?

Comment: What in the world is $I$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah! I forgot! $\text{I}$ is the centre of $\text{[GF]}$.

Comment: This certainly looks way wrong from pictures, so we can give a counterexample. Where did you come up with this?

Comment: @TedShifrin Just as I've seen, maybe we should write: $\vec{\text{EG}}=\vec{\text{AA'}}$ ?

Comment: With that alteration, the result seems plausible.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, I'll try with $\vec{\text{EG}}=\vec{\text{AA'}}$ ...

Comment: Can you give your source ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo What I can hear in the back of the class from the teacher.

Comment: Probably the thesis of 2. is $\;\overrightarrow {EI}=x \cdot \overrightarrow {AA'}\,$ or $\,\overrightarrow {AA'}=x \cdot \overrightarrow {EI}$.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I'll try it right now

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I found $\,\overrightarrow {A'A}= 2 \cdot \overrightarrow {EI}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem**:
*Given a triangle $XYZ\,$, if $X'$ is the center of $\,[YZ]$, then* $$\overrightarrow {XX'}=\frac 12 \cdot (\overrightarrow {XY}+\overrightarrow {XZ})$$In fact $$\overrightarrow {XX'}=\overrightarrow {XY}+\overrightarrow {YX'}$$$$\overrightarrow {XX'}=\overrightarrow {XZ}+\overrightarrow {ZX'}$$After summing side by side, we are done.

Now your question:

1.$$\overrightarrow {AA'}+\overrightarrow {BB'}+\overrightarrow {CC'}=$$$$\frac 12 \cdot (\overrightarrow {AB}+\overrightarrow {AC}+\overrightarrow {BA}+\overrightarrow {BC}+\overrightarrow {CA}+\overrightarrow {CB})=0$$2.$$\overrightarrow {EI}=\frac 12 \cdot (\overrightarrow {EF}+\overrightarrow {EG})=$$$$\frac 12 \cdot (\overrightarrow {CC'}+\overrightarrow {BB'})=$$$$\frac 14 \cdot (\overrightarrow {CA}+\overrightarrow {CB}+\overrightarrow {BC}+\overrightarrow {BA})=$$$$-\frac 14 \cdot (\overrightarrow {AC}+\overrightarrow {AB})=$$$$-\frac 12 \cdot \overrightarrow {AA'}$$

Comment: Here is my easier solution:
We have: $$\vec{\text{AA'}}+\vec{\text{BB'}}+\vec{\text{CC'}}=\vec{\text{0}} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\vec{\text{BB'}}=\vec{\text{EG}}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\vec{\text{CC'}}=\vec{\text{EF}}$$ so: $$\vec{\text{EG}}+\vec{\text{EF}}=\vec{\text{A'A}}$$ Thus: $$2\vec{\text{EI}}=\vec{\text{A'A}}$$

Comment: Bravo ! you used part 1.